# C# Windows Service Threading Process Improve Performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

We developed windows services with using threads to consume database records(generally .Net 2.0).Code block under the show.

```
for(int i=0;i<ThreadCount;i++)
{
   ParameterizedThreadStart pts=new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyCode.DoWork)
   Thread t=new Thread(pts);
    t.Start(someObject);
}
```

ThreadCount read from app.config.MyCode.DoWork(Object someObject) code block select with some data in SQL server,and some operations.In addition to we call sp,and the query contains with(rowlock) vs.

```
while(someObject.Running)
{
   */select some data
}
```

Main question is how to improve my windows service.Some article related to manual creating thread increase CPU cost vs.So how to improve my app performance.If i use Parallel Task Library bring to any advantage.Create a task instead of create thread.Does Task create thread manually to look available CPU count,or i convert to like.

```
for(int i=0;i<ThreadCount;i++){

   Task t=new Task(=>MyCode.Work());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that CPU is problem here, for me looks like DB is bottleneck? Do you measure performance? For starters you may try Parallel.For it will adjust number of treads automatically.

Comment: There is no CPU issue,but i'm trying to improve my performance.(sometimes CPU and DB explore programming,because of we had a many windows service,doing some operations db).Because we want operate our data as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the performance of your application, you need to find out where the performance is lacking and then why it's lacking. Unfortunately we can't do that for you, because it needs access to the running C# and SQL code.

I suggest doing some performance profiling, either with a profiler tool (I use [Redgate's tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)) or by adding profiling code to your application. Once you can see the bottlenecks, you can make a theory about what's causing them.

I would start with the database first - look at the cached execution plans to see if there are any clues. Try running the stored procedures separately from the service.

Comment: Especially,there is no constant CPU or DB problem.I only want to improve my performance.I curies about that,cause we operate data as soon as possible.If we use Parallel Library coming any issue.

Comment: If there's no CPU or database problem, then where is the code slow?

Comment: I  curious about that if i processing about 5 minutes some data operation,how to decrease to like 3,5 minutes.

Comment: Maybe you have issues with excessive locking of DB rows. Do you check how you db server performs (especially since you use exclusive locks)

Answer (score 0):

to make things simpler and assuming the windows service is the only client accessing the database.
1. try to access the database from one thread. this reduces lock contention on db tables assuming there is contention in accessing data.
2. put the data retrieved into a queue and have TPL tasks processing the data to utilize all CPU cores assuming your performance bottle neck is the cpu
3. and then buy as many cpu core as you can afford.

This is an intuitive pattern and there are many assumptions in it. You'll need to profile and analyze your program to know whether this is suitable.